# AWS lambda invoking locally works but prod errors with 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam

My functions work in local with `sam local invoke` but when testing in AWS all of them are failing with below error. What is the problem? I'm using axios but that shouldn't give any error.

````
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Request failed with status code 403",
  "trace": [
    "Error: Error: Request failed with status code 403",
    "    at Runtime.<anonymous> (/var/task/app.js:2:1014144)",
    "    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)",
    "    at n (/var/task/app.js:2:1013200)",
    "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)"
  ]
}```
````

Comment: Did you check logs in CloudWatch logs?

Comment: It's a scrapping function and I haven't connected to VPC. I think that seems to be the problem.